# How to use inkscape to import a vector graphic in LaTeX

Tags: svg, inkscape

I am trying to include a nice vector graphic in my LaTeX document. Obviously, I am doing this, because I don't want the quality of my figures to decrease when zooming in. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is what I was thinking: 
I have created a figure in Inkscape. I have saved the figure as `.svg`. I have also saved the figure as `.pdf_tex` (this file is auto-generated by inkscape when saving the figure as `.pdf`).

Now I am trying to include the `.pdf_tex` figure in my document:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
    \input{figures/network.pdf_tex}
    \caption{Graphical Representation of Scenario.}
    \label{Scenario}
\end{figure}
```

I am using a customized template. In the options I have included the following line, since I get the error message `` Package pdftex.def Error: File `network.pdf' not found. ...cs[width=\unitlength,page=1]{network.pdf}} ``

```
\graphicspath{{./figures}}
```

Right, I forgot to mention: the same error message still occurs. Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome  to TeX SX! I guess the extension `.pdf_tex` is not known to graphicx, hence it is looking for a simple `.pdf` graphic file, which it doesn't  find. I suggest you change the extension given by `svg`  to  `.pdf`.

Comment: Thx for your reply, Bernard! - But I'm afraid this is not solving the issue. I have included the figure just the way it is described here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf  .. I have changed `{graphicspath{{figures/}}` , and of course I tried out your solution by simply renaming the ending to .pdf

Comment: Maybe you should give a try to the `svg` package?

Comment: Open `network.pdf_tex` with an editor, and in lines 5 -- 6 you will read: "
**%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}**
"

Your tex document needs at minimum to load a document class and packages color and graphicx.

Comment: can it be that the documentclass I am using is the problem? - It is a template that was given to me. Because I am already using `\iput{<filename>.pdf_tex}` and it doesn't work, even when separately including color and graphicx packages

Comment: ok, I finally managed to include the figure! I had to open the .pdf_tex file and in the line saying \includegraphics {network.pdf_tex} delete the .pdf_tex ending.. I now only have one last problem: the figure is about 1/3 of the page. The caption, however, appears at the bottom of the page. I'm afraid this could be due to inkscape saving the whole page with the figure on it? How can I change this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments